# Install Previous Version of CouchDB on Mac

Tags: macos, couchdb

I was able to install couchdb's latest version on Mac OS using Homebrew.Is there a way i could install the previous version (0.10.0).I have tried using iriscouch but could not clone the repositories.

What about installing versions like 1.1.1 is there a way to do that using homebrew?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current release is 1.2.0, and the previous one is 1.1.1. 0.10.0 is a *long* way back in CouchDB history. Are you sure you need that far back? What's the issue you are having?

For 1.1.1 you can simply revert to the previous formula (check it out via git) or simply edit the couchdb.rb file directly.

If you need 0.10.0, another alternative is to try https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb.

Finally, try building Erlang R14B01 from source, spidermonkey 1.7.0 and then using a similar configuration as in the 0.10.0 homebrew recipe:

require 'brewkit'

class Couchdb

depends_on 'spidermonkey'
  depends_on 'icu4c'
  depends_on 'erlang'

def install
    system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}",
                          "--localstatedir=#{var}",
                          "--sysconfdir=#{etc}",
                          "--with-erlang=#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/lib/erlang/usr/include"
    system "make"
    system "make install"

```
(var+'lib'+'couchdb').mkpath
(var+'log'+'couchdb').mkpath
```

end
end

Both CouchDB, Mac OS X, Erlang, Spidermonkey & other dependencies have evolved significantly since late 2009 when 0.10.0 was released. Expect some bumps in the road.

Comment: Thanks dch for the reply. I still could not manage it to work and you were right about the bumps along the way.0.10.0 is way back but is is possible to install a much newer version like 1.1.1 without all of this hassle and in a simple way?

Comment: @Qamar you have not told us what issues we're having, so we can't know what hassles you're facing.